# Scrape HTML webpage using R

Tags: html, r, function, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape past results of every MLB team on covers.com going back to 2007. An example page can be found here: http://www.covers.com/pageLoader/pageLoader.aspx?page=/data/mlb/teams/pastresults/2016/team2979.html.

I have the following code:

```
for (year in 2007:2016) {
    for (id in 2955:2984){
        url <- paste0("http://www.covers.com/pageLoader/pageLoader.aspx?page=/data/mlb/teams/pastresults/", year, "/team", id, ".html")
    data <- readHTMLTable(url, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    data <- data[[1]]
    data$year <- year
    data$id <- id
    }
}
```

Which at first glance works, but then only returns a dataframe consisting of 9 observations of 9 variables that are Toronto's 9 playoff games played in October 2016. Obviously, I'm missing something here? Any help is much appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Every time you get new data,  you are over-writing the old data. You need to append it.  I also had to make a little hack here because the 300 tables that you are trying to load had slightly inconsistent names. Also, it was taking too long to download 300 tables,  so I changed your limits to only get two teams for two years. When you are convinced it is working,  you can change it back to get all 300.

Trying to stay close to your code:

```
library("XML")
data = c()
for (year in 2007:2008) {
    for (id in 2955:2956){
            url <- paste0("http://www.covers.com/pageLoader/pageLoader.aspx?page=/data/mlb/teams/pastresults/", 
                year, "/team", id, ".html")
            temp <- readHTMLTable(url, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
            temp <- temp[[1]]
            temp$year <- year
            temp$id <- id
        if(is.data.frame(data)) { 
            names(temp) = names(data)
            data = rbind(data, temp) 
        } else {
            data=temp
        }
    }
}
dim(data)
[1] 498   9
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
data <- lapply(2007:2016,function(x){
    lapply(2955:2956,function(y){
    url <- paste0("http://www.covers.com/pageLoader/pageLoader.aspx?page=/data/mlb/teams/pastresults/", x, "/team", y, ".html")
    readHTMLTable(url, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
        })
})

names(data) <- paste0("x",as.character(2007:2016))
for(i in paste0("x",as.character(2007:2016))) names(data[[i]]) <- paste0("x",as.character(2955:2956))
```

Your data will be in a nested list called data afterward. You can then access each table by using: `data$x2007$x2955` as it is a nested list.